# Have nginx call an external script (passing request info) while serving static file?

Tags: php, nginx, readfile

I'm setting up download logging on a server that hosts podcast recordings. We just want to easily log into MySQL the files downloaded with the timestamp and requesting IP address.

As these files average at least 150MB, I figured using readfile() would be a bad idea (don't want PHP running the entire time the file is downloading), and instead would have to have the files stored in a different location that PHP redirects them to after logging.

The problem of course is that once they're redirected, they could potentially copy that redirected link and use that, inadvertently bypassing the download logging. I'd like to avoid that.

I'm thinking my best bet would be to have nginx configured to call a secondary script before serving the file, passing the request data to it for processing. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule

```
location /file {
   content_by_lua 'os.execute("php cli.php ',ngx.var.remote_addr,'")';
}
```

Not sure about the syntax passing IP but smth like this should work. You can also parse log file

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I ended up using access_by_lua and having the code be a `ngx.location.capture` call to my download logging script. Using `content_by_lua` seemed to prevent the actual serving of the requested file.